# Compile error due to tex file having a UNC path

Tags: compiling, paths, sublime-text

I'm trying to compile a LaTex document using the LaTeXing package in ST3. If the file is on my local disk 'C:*' it compiles fine, but I have to keep it on a networked drive '\[company_site]*' which I believe is referred to as a UNC path. Trying to compile the document from the networked location gives me the following error (personal info removed):

```
E: \\[company_address]\[path]\report.tex:0 Undefined control sequence
E: \\[company_address]\[path]\report.tex:0 Undefined control sequence
E: \\[company_address]\[path]\report.tex:0 Undefined control sequence
E: \\[company_address]\[path]\report.tex:0 Emergency stop
```

I guess the backslashes at the start cause the path to be interpreted as a command. How can I edit my build command to fix this error?

Comment: Exactly how are you compiling here? Manually in a dos promt, or through an editor?

Comment: Did you try with `/` instead of \?

Comment: @daleif I'm compiling through the editor. Running pdflatex in a dos prompt works fine, but I think the editor uses latexmk which I'm not sure how to use, so I can't check that. It would be much more convenient to get it to work through the editor.

Comment: @egreg The path is automatically generated. I don't know how I would change the slashes.

Comment: When you open the file, do you double click on it? I have seen this before, the editor will end up with one path specification if you double click and another (working) path if you start the editor and then navigate to the file via the `File -> Open` interface. (it is a real pain the B**!

Comment: @daleif Using `File -> Open` makes no difference.

Comment: Which editor? Can it compile if you use the dos prompt? The file manager will usually show you the driber letter the UNC path is associated with. Then navigate to that driver right into the folder holding `report.tex` and ompile it there. Don't specify full path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I fixed it by passing the filename as the argument instead of the whole path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Windows backslash file path seperator `\` is used in (La)TeX to indicate a control sequence (aka. macro). That is why you get a `Undefined control sequence` error. In this case it takes `\report` as a macro.

Normally you need to exchange it with the Unix file path seperator `/` instead, which under (La)Tex also works under Windows. Not sure if network paths work, I never tried that.

You could also try to wrap the file name in an `\unexpanded{ .. }` statement (doesn't work with very old or nonstandard LaTeX versions), which might work or not dependent on the underlying implementation of the macro you are using to process the file path.